# Running find and xargs in background

Tags: linux, find, xargs

I want to run this command in background because the process could take a long time. How can I send it to a background process?

```
find /tmp/ -type f -mtime +3 | xargs rm -Rf
```

This does not work:

```
find /tmp/ -type f -mtime +3 | xargs rm -Rf &
```

How can I do this instead?

Comment: Wait, your second example *should* work (except for the spaces problem slhck mentions).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to run both in background, put them in a subshell:

```
(find /tmp/ -type f -mtime +3 | xargs rm -Rf) &
```

But, please, **don't do this**. Piping `find` output into `xargs` is unsafe unless you use the following options, which are supported in GNU and BSD `find` and `xargs`:

```
find … -print0 | xargs -0 …
```

If `find` returned files with spaces in their name you could – without even knowing – irreversibly delete the wrong folders. Carefully read the `find` manual and the [section about deleting files](http://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_mono/find.html#Deleting-Files) for more info.

The safest way, in your case, would be:

```
find /tmp/ -type f -mtime +3 -delete &
```

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the hardware that the filesystem is sitting on it may be faster to delete in parallel:

```
( find . | parallel -X rm ) &
```

In contrast to `xargs` GNU Parallel deals correctly with space, " and ' in file names. Only if you have file names containing newline you will need -print0/-0.

10 seconds installation:

```
wget -O - pi.dk/3 | bash
```

Watch the intro video for a quick introduction:
https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL284C9FF2488BC6D1